SSL Handshake Exception When Building Flutter Plugin
I generated a Flutter plugin with the following command:
flutter create --template=plugin --platforms=android,ios new_plug

When I execute the plugin I am getting below as the exception.
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.test:runner:1.2+.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :integration_test
      > Failed to list versions for androidx.test:runner.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/runner/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/runner/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Failed to list versions for androidx.test:runner.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/runner/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/runner/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve androidx.test:rules:1.2+.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :integration_test
      > Failed to list versions for androidx.test:rules.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/rules/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/rules/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Failed to list versions for androidx.test:rules.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/rules/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/rules/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2+.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :integration_test
      > Failed to list versions for androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/espresso/espresso-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/espresso/espresso-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Failed to list versions for androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/espresso/espresso-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/espresso/espresso-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 34s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Project Structure is below:
Click to view project structure
What I have tried till now:

I have tried creating a new file named gradle.properties under the android folder and put the below line in it. The android directory was at the same level as the example directory.

systemProp.gradle.internal.http.connectionTimeout=60000
systemProp.gradle.internal.http.socketTimeout=60000
systemProp.gradle.internal.http.sslVerify=false

Versions Info:

Android Studio Koala 2024.1.1
Android SDK 14.0 API level 34

Thank you for helping in advance :)

Do you use internet connection of a company? The output may indicate that they have set-up network inspection system that acts as a man-in-the-middle attack on the TLS connection. The attack is recognized by gradle as it does not trust the root certificate used by the inspection system => ask your admins

Yes the internet connection might be monitored or something because this is companies laptop. You got any idea of what rights shall I ask the admins so that the plugin runs fine?

Android Studio and Gradle use Java and it's trust store. You would have to modify this Java runtime trust store and include the company root Ca certificate in it to make it work. or as the admins for an exception/bypass for dl.google.com-

Sure, @Robert. Thanks for the help.
